# how to allow users to add their own disqus comment box

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, disqus

We have a simple website that lets users create a blog at http://www.example.com/username which individual posts at http://www.example.com/posts/1234 etc. Is it possible to let the user add their own disqus comment box so they can moderate the comments on their blog themselves?